# How to add elements of other arrays in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays, one of product titles and another of quantities. I need to store them in a new array, which has in its first position "title" and "quantity".

This is what I thought:

```
//arrayTitle and arrayQuantity already come with stored data, both arrays of the same length

$newArray[];

for($i=0;$i<count($arrayTitle);$i++){

$newArray = array("title" => value of the position $i of the title array,
"quantity" => value of the position $i of the quantity array);

}
```

Comment: Use `$arrayTitle[$i]` to select specific item of array. Also use `$newArray[] = array(...` to insert new array to variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with an foreach loop, like:

```
foreach ($arrayTitle as $i => $title) {
    $newArray[] = [
        'title' => $title,
        'quantity' => $arrayQuantity[$i]
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just map them to callback that returns them in your array format:

```
$newArray = array_map(function($t, $q) { 
                          return array("title" => $t, "quantity" => $q);
                      }, $arrayTitle, $arrayQuantity);
```

Comment: I was thinking use this with `array_combine` for the key but this way better

Comment: Great idea. In this way, each element of the arrays of titles and quantities are saved?